# How to configure OWIN OpenID Connect middleware to validate all token aspects without custom validators in .NET Framework 4.6.2?

Tags: validation, asp.net-identity, token, openid-connect, owin

I am using OWIN OpenID Connect middleware in a .NET Framework 4.6.2 project, and I want to validate all aspects of the ID tokens without writing custom validators for the issuer or the signing key. Currently, my configuration looks like this:

```cs
// ... Owin setup code ...

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    // ... other options ...

    TokenValidationParameters = GetTokenValidationParameter(options),

    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        // ... other notifications ...
    }
});

// ... other code ...
```

And here is the `GetTokenValidationParameter` method, where I'm setting up the token validation parameters:

```cs
public static TokenValidationParameters GetTokenValidationParameter(OidcSsoOptions options)
{
    var jwks = GetJWKS(options.JwksUrl); // this is for fetching JWKS from URL.
    var signingKeys = new JsonWebKeySet(jwks).GetSigningKeys();

    var result = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidIssuer = options.AuthBaseUrl,
        ValidAudience = options.Audience,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKeys = signingKeys,
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        RequireSignedTokens = false,

        IssuerValidator = (issuer, securityToken, validationParameters) =>
        {
            // Custom issuer validation logic...
        },

        IssuerSigningKeyValidator = (securityKey, securityToken, validationParameters) =>
        {
            // Custom signing key validation logic...
        }
    };

    return result;
}
```

I noticed that if I don't implement the `IssuerValidator` and `IssuerSigningKeyValidator` delegates in the `TokenValidationParameters`, the validation is bypassed, and I want the middleware to perform the validation automatically without using custom code.

**How can I achieve this? Is there a way to configure the OWIN OpenID Connect middleware to perform all the necessary validations without implementing custom validators?**